# How to get a sum of a grouped column and insert into a separate table field?

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following query to get the number of unique location codes per account number:

```
SELECT  acct_num, location, count(acct_num) as total_acct
FROM client_table
GROUP BY acct_num, location
ORDER BY acct_num
```

I get the following result

```
+---------+------------+-----------+
|acct_num | location   | total_acct|
+---------+------------+-----------+
|    1    |  ABS_ONE   |        22 |
|    1    |  ABS_TWO   |        18 |
|    1    |  ABS_THREE |        12 |
|    2    |  ANTHR_LOC |         9 |
+---------+------------+-----------+
```

What I want after this, is the total locations per account (So acct_num 1 would be 52), and then insert that total into a total locations field in a second table, related by the acct_num field. I am thinking that it should be using the above query as a subquery, but not sure how to structure it?

Comment: Use the aggregate functions `sum` for example

Comment: @ACV - I tried that, but I got an error about temporary tables and references that I didn't understand, and then not sure after that how to update the secondary table.

Comment: I think you need to create a View

Comment: You can use WITH ROLLUP, but I'd just do that bit in application level code

Comment: @Strawberry - Never heard ot that function, but there is no application. I'm doing this in mysql workbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW TEMP_SUM AS
SELECT  acct_num, location, count(acct_num) as total_acct
FROM client_table
GROUP BY acct_num, location
ORDER BY acct_num
```

And then.

```
SELECT SUM(total_acct) FROM TEMP_SUM
GROUP BY acct_num
```

Comment: Ok, that worked well, thank you! Figured out the update using this as a subquery, much appreciated!